# How to make this program "beautiful"?

Tags: python

Please refer below code:

```
import numpy as np

def MakeRandomFlag():

  a = np.random.randint(1,5, size=10)
  return a[3]
```

```
Type1=0
Type2=0
Type3=0
Type4=0
Type5=0

for i in range(10):
  CollectResult = MakeRandomFlag()
  if(CollectResult == 1):
    Type1+=1
  if(CollectResult == 2):
    Type2+=1
  if(CollectResult == 3):
    Type3+=1
  if(CollectResult == 4):
    Type4+=1
  if(CollectResult == 5):
    Type5+=1

print(Type0,Type1,Type2,Type3,Type4)
```

I feel so many if(CollectResult == 1) statement makes code look very ugly.
Any idea to improve it would be very appreciate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: By using a `list` to store your counts

Comment: @DavidS , thank you for let me know codereview website.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the results in a dictionnary:

```py
results = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0}
for i in range(10):
  c = MakeRandomFlag()
  if c in results: # This is only necessary if you're not *sure* that `c` is in {1,2,3,4,5}
    results[c] += 1
```

A list could also be used instead of the dictionary, if you only have to deal with contiguous integers.

Comment: It is very beautiful~